# Go struct field has same name as interface method

Tags: go

From a 3rd party:

```
package lib

type Bar interface{
  Age() int
}

Foo(b Bar) int
```

This doesn't compile because `Age` is both a method name and field name:

```
package main

import "lib"

type Person struct {
  Age int
}

func (p *Person)Age() int {
  return p.Age
}

func main() {
  p := Person()
  lib.Foo(p)
}
```

**Without** renaming `Person.Age`, is there a way to call `lib.Foo()` on an instance of `Person`?

Comment: No, because, as you noted, you can't have a field and method with the same name, and you have to implement the `Age` method to satisfy the interface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, not directly, of course, for the reasons already stated.  But you could create a wrapper around Person, and pass that in:

```
type BarPerson struct {
    *Person
}

func (bp *BarPerson) Age() int {
    return bp.Person.Age
}

func main() {
    p := Person{37}
    lib.Foo(&BarPerson{&p})
}
```